# compare time in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel experts, need your help to compute the check column, details below.

```
Column A             | Column B                | Column C        | Column D           | Check
12/07/2012  23:59:06 | 2012/07/12              | Thursday        | 23:59:06           |  ?
            -        | =TEXT(A2, "yyyy/mm/dd") | =TEXT(A3,"dddd")|=TEXT(A3,"HH:mm:ss")|
```

As you can see, I am extracting the date in column B, I am extracting the day in Column C, I have the time being extracted in Column D.

Column Check should be true if the below condition is met and false otherwise:

1. If day is Saturday or Sunday then should be true
2. If day is Monday to Friday and Time is > 6:30 pm and time < 07:30 am should be true.

This is the formula I have build which does not seem to work.

```
=IF(OR(C2="Saturday",C2="Sunday")+OR((D2>TIME(18,0,0)*AND(D2<TIME(7,0,0)))),TRUE,FALSE)
```

I get true for pretty much everything. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write something like `A OR B OR C`, in excel 2010, you can simply write: `OR(A, B, C)`.

In your case, it would be:

```
=OR(C2="Saturday",C2="Sunday",D2>TIME(18,0,0), D2<TIME(7,0,0))
```

I think you also need to use a proper time in column D instead of text:

```
=TIME(HOUR(A2),MINUTE(A2),SECOND(A2))
```

Comment: TIME(HOUR(A2),MINUTE(A2),SECOND(A2)) results in 19/01/00 HH:MM:SS is there no way to ditch the date component. Or use the date because it will consistanly be 19/01/00 only?