# how to write note in avd?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an emulator in eclipse.

Did i need another things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel stores time internally the same way as date - i.e. `1` equals one full day, namely January 1st, 1900. Thus, one hour is `1/24`. Assuming that only the time was entered into the cell (and not a full date with a time), you could therefore use this formula:

```
=IF(U7>16/24+50/(24*60),U7-(16/24+50/(24*60)),0)
```

Alternatively, you could use Excel's `TIME` function, which converts hours, minutes and seconds into an Excel time:

```
=IF(U7>TIME(16,50,0),U7-TIME(16,50,0),0)
```

In case your input cell is a full date with a time, you need to either get rid of the date in the input value - or add the date to the comparison - though I'd recommend the former:

```
=IF(TIME(HOUR(U7),MINUTE(U7),SECOND(U7))>TIME(16,50,0),U7-TIME(16,50,0),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following article, I hope this will help you.

[compare time in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519719/compare-time-in-excel)

You should compare time in following way -

U7>TIME(16,50,0)  inside the IF condition.

Please make sure that the column U7 which you use as time input, should be in proper Time format.

Thanks.